# Setting the base url inside a anchor tag href in VueJS

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, share

In my Vue JS application I have a component to share a link on twitter and Facebook. Following is my code for twitter share option

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=Verbatim&url=https://test.sample.site/&hashtags=hashtag1,hashtag2,hashtag3">
```

I have two environments. Test and Live. Because of that when ever I change the environment I have to change the `url` parameter of he anchor tag manually. But without seting that manually, I'm trying to put he base url inside that anchor.

Eg: Instead of using  `https://test.sample.site` how can I set the base url?

Comment: You can able to use `url()` method to get base URL like `echo url('');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.location.origin`.

in `data` property:

```
data: () => {
    return {
      baseUrl: window.location.origin,
    };
},
```

And in `template` section:

```
<a :href="`http://twitter.com/share?text=Verbatim&url=${baseUrl}&hashtags=hashtag1,hashtag2,hashtag3`"
>link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laraval has provided methods to get base URL:

```
// Get the base URL.
echo url('');

// .env file set app URL
echo config('app.url');
```

If you needed current URL then use below method:

```
echo url()->current();
```

As per your requirement:

`<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=Verbatim&url={{ url('') }}/&hashtags=hashtag1,hashtag2,hashtag3">example</a>`